Name of military movie with song R.O.C.K. In the USA
I apologize for not having much to go on but for years I've been trying to remember a movie that I can only remember a few pieces from. I know it's several years old. The main scene sticking with me is a group of young soldiers riding in the back of a covered truck with them singing along to the song 'R.O.C.K. In the USA'. Then they are maybe crossing a border or something and the guy they pull the truck up to ask them something like "where are you boys from" and they all yell "THE USA" (paralleling the song).
Also, I'm not sure if it's the same movie or perhaps another movie entirely but the scene is again of young soldiers training outside in the dark and the rain. Rolling around in mud. (For some reason I think I recall there being a Manila envelope with some documents in it)?
I completely understand this may be the worst recounting of a movie but it's all I remember and I can't get it out of my head. I've been wondering for years but it's not easy to Google such odd and vague details. 
Thanks for any help or suggestions. Sorry for the annoying lack of information.  

I am only going off of 'military movie' coupled with the song you mentioned here, but it might be "Renaissance Man" from 1994.

Can you define "several years old", as currently we don't know how many years counted as several years.

I think you made a list of military movie tropes. :)

I know I know I'm terrible. Several years would be maybe 13 years ago? I'm guessing but I saw it at home so it was television at the point. I would say it's maybe 15-20 years old now? That seems old...i don't know here the time goes. The year 2000 seems like yesterday.

I do appreciate your kindness! I have given you extremely little detail.

So, it's not Renaissance Man?

THAT'S IT!!! Thank you thank you thank you! Sorry I hadn't looked at that previously! You're awesome! I'm so happy you've helped me finally figure this okay!  ...and I won't hold it against you that you are presumably a Pittsburgh Steelers fan! :)

Answer posted...even thogh you are a Steelers hater ;)

I could never find the name of that movie either.. I'm gonna check to see if it is that movie...

I think this movie came out in the 80s because my sister and I fell in love with it we both lived at home and I graduated in 1990.. we only saw it 1 time at home on satilite

The name of the movie you are looking for is "Renaissance Man" from 1994 starring Danny DeVito and directed by Penny Marshall:

A down-on-his-luck businessman desperately takes the only job offered
  - a teacher in the U.S. Army. His mission: keep a ragtag bunch of underachieving misfits from flunking out of basic training! Be on
  alert as this unlikely new teacher and his underdog class unexpectedly
  inspire each other to be all they can be!

The movie contains the song "R.O.C.K. in the USA" performed by John Mellencamp.
